# Cannot resolve symbol QueryParser Lucene 7.5

Tags: java, apache, lucene

When writing the following code:

`QueryParser qp = new QueryParser("id", new StandardAnalyzer());`,

IntelliJ IDEA gives me the error: **Cannot resolve symbol 'QueryParser'**.

I've also explicitly imported the following library

`import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser;`,

but this also gives me the following error: **Cannot resolve symbol 'queryparser'**.

I am using Lucene 7.5, and added the `.jar` file from core directory to

Project Structure -> Modules -> Dependencies -> + Sign -> JARs or Directories and add Lucene `.jar` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lucene ships with several JARs. Did you include `lucene-queryparser-7.5.0.jar` in addition to `lucene-core-7.5.0.jar`? It's in the `queryparser/` directory next to the `core/` directory. Add that one too and it should resolve.

Comment: Great, thanks. I had to add the other jar files, exactly like you said.